# Как засунуть в переменную предложение?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Как сделать так чтобы в переменную fb могло поместиться предложение? Или несколько слов.

```
@bot.command()
async def fb(ctx, fb, ocenka:int):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1091628317871976528)
    em = discord.Embed(title="Отзыв:", description=f"Новый отзыв от пользователя {ctx.message.author} .\n"
                                                   f"Отзыв: {fb}\n"
                                                   f"Оценка: {ocenka}/5", color=0x1f8b4c)
    await channel.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: попробуйте написать в аргументах ```ctx, *, fb, ocenka:int```. Должно помочь

Comment: @Rastrey ошибка: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: fb() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'ocenka'

Answer (score 0):

Перепишите Ваш код вот так:

```
@bot.command()
async def fb(ctx, ocenka:int, *, fb):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1091628317871976528)
    em = discord.Embed(title="Отзыв:", description=f"Новый отзыв от пользователя {ctx.message.author} .\n"
                                                   f"Отзыв: {fb}\n"
                                                   f"Оценка: {ocenka}/5", color=0x1f8b4c)
    await channel.send(embed=em)
```

Теперь использование команды будет выглядеть так:
`!fb 5 самый лучший вообще отзыв да`

И всё будет работать